# Hibernate: TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance when fetching entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jhipster

my scenario is this:

My entity has a relation:

```
@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "currency2dossiers", allowSetters = true)
private Currency originalCurrency;
```

in my service, I first save a new entity with all field set to null to have the id and then, in a new Object I set all fields except the originalCurrency that is nullable.

during the 'setting fase' I need to fetch a related entity (with findAll) and I get:

```
 org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : it.openway.technital.co.domain.Dossier.originalCurrency -> it.openway.technital.co.domain.Currency
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.noCascade(CascadingActions.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
```

I don't understand why the exception is related to Currency -> originalCurrency which is not required and will not be set.
I've already tried CascadeType.ALL and other solution to similar questions with no success.

Comment: You should add some code more. In any case it seems you are saving the entity by using a reference do Currency not stored in the DB. So, according to hibernate, this Currency is transient AKA unsaved

Comment: @AngeloImmediata yes It's exactly as you describe. Is there a good practice to solve the problem? I wish to save the entity but not the related one because should be null. Is the entity designed in the wrong way?

Comment: You must set nullable the related entity in jpa mapping

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: The exception is due to the way the front end sends data. It passes an object like:
"originalCurrency":{"id":null}

if I pass "originalCurrency":null in Postman it works fine.
Thanks for your help anyway.